# A way to determine type of derived class with minimum code in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, abi, typeinfo, demangler

I have a class (Say A) with many subclasses and 4 level inheritance. I have wrote function type in Base class to determine the type of class as below:

```
const string A::type() const {
    int status;
    const char *  realName;
    string name;
    const std::type_info &ti = typeid(*this);
    realName = abi::__cxa_demangle(ti.name(), 0, 0, &status);

    name= realName;
    int index =name.find_last_of(':');
    name = name.substr(index+1, name.length()-index-1);
    free((void *) realName);
    return name;
}
```

This is working with this code:

```
B tmp("temp");
    cout<<tmp.type() // Prints "B"
```

But not with this code:

```
A  tmp = B("temp");
    cout<<tmp.type() // Prints "A"
```

I have a `vector<A>` which can take any subclass. Is there a way to force A to return back the type of the derived class?

Comment: if A is Base and B is derived calling this  `A  tmp = B("temp");` I'm pretty sure that causes slicing.

Comment: @101010 So how can I fix it with vector<A&> for example?

Comment: You can't have a vector of references because references don't satisfy the concept of erasable. However, you can have a vector of `vector<A*>`.

Comment: ok thank you @101010